# Possible to search google for which sites link to a particular URL?

Tags: search

Is it possible to search Google (or elsewhere) to find which sites link to a particular URL? For example, find the sites that link to www.apple.com/osx/whatever.pdf ?

Comment: Is this for your own site?

Comment: Google for `link:http://www.apple.com/osx/whatever.pdf`. Then please read [what is on-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

If this is for your own website, you can take a look at Google Analytics or a similar analytics/conversion tracking.